# Excel VBA: Cell populating to infinity

Tags: vba, cell, activex, populate

I have the below VBA code in an ActiveX button:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim rng as Range

Set rng = Sheets("Declines").Range("H:H")
Sheets("Declines").Activate
rng.Select
Selection.Replace What:="", Replacement:="0"

End Sub
```

What is basically does is populate blank cells in the H column with "0", but the problem is that does ti all the way down to 100000.

I want it to stop populating when it reaches the last value of adjacent cells, as opposed to doing it all the way down. I would be very grateful if someone could help.

Let me know if further clarification is needed. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Declines").Range("H1:H" & sheets("Declines").Usedrange.rows.count).Replace What:="", Replacement:="0"
```

Comment: Seems to do the same thing, I'm afraid.